# Filtering 4K and 60FPS results from Youtube API and Search->List

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube API v3 with a website for searching Gaming streams.  For Gaming, 4K and 60FPS are *critical* for some users...

While the Search->List seems quite extensive, it's missing filters for 4K and 60 FPS.  The only relevant option seems to be videoDefinition='high' (720p+).  Also, Video->List->FileDetails information is only available to channel owners.  Am I missing something?  How do I filter the search to only 4K and/or 48+ FPS?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there is no method in the YouTube API now that can filter the result base on FPS. Like you said the only way to filter the video by its quality is by using the [`videoDefinition`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoDefinition) but only has standard and high option.

I try to check the quality of different video by using the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) method and use the `contentDetails` as a part to view the definition. By using this way, I only get a definition result of `"hd"`. All the high quality videos that I try has the same result of `"hd"`

Here is the example request that I use to check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pxRHBw-k8M)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=6pxRHBw-k8M&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```